# arcmap 10.6 shapefiles do not display in OpenLayers 4.6.5

Tags: openlayers, shapefile, geoserver

I have been using Geoserver for 10 years.

After upgrading to ArcMap 10.6, I find that when I export to a shapefile, 
my feature does not display in OpenLayers 4.6.5 with projection EPSG:900913 anymore. It does display in the GeoServer 10.13.0 OpenLayers preview with its native EPSG:2249 projection.

I do not know if this is significant, but when i use shp2pgsql on an old and a new shapefile, the .sql files differ in that the "**shape_leng**","shape_area" went

from: `'7.34326200731e+001','2.91698658023e+002'`

to: `'7.34326200731e+01','2.91698658023e+02'`

note the additional digit in the exponent.

Comment: the problem appears limited to one feature class, other ArcMap 10.6 shapefiles are working in openLayers.

Comment: It works if I use the shapefile as the geoserver store, but not when i load the .sql into postgresql

Comment: objectid, shape_length and shape_area show up as type BigDecimal in the shapefile input to postgresql, they are type long or double for shapefiles

Comment: there is no GeoServer 10.13.0

Comment: what error messages do you see?

Comment: oops-GeoServer 2.13.0

Comment: I do not see any error messages- just no features display

Comment: try turning the logging level up and check again

Comment: I set logging to verbose, still no errors

Comment: I found it by zooming out way beyond the boundaries of my data. Must be a projection issue

Comment: the shapelength seems to be off by a factor of 3.28= number of feet in a meter

Answer (score 0):

My stupid mistake- the data is in MA state plane meters and I was telling GeoServer to use Feet